# Unable to use System.Serializable/SerializedField for an AudioManager component I'm building

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using a basic script for an audio manager but I'm getting errors, not sure what's going on?

Tried "using System;" instead, same issues.

```
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]

public class Sound {
    public string name;
    public AudioClip clip;
    private AudioSource source;

    public float volume = 0.7;
    public float pitch = 1f;

    public void SetSource (AudioSource _source) {
        source = _source;
        source.clip = clip;
    }

    public void Play () {
        source.volume = volume;
        source.pitch = pitch;
        source.Play();
    }
}

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializedField]
    Source[] sounds;

}
```

I expect this to add fields to the "Audio Manager" i'm building

Comment: Assets/AudioManager.cs(26,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SerializedFieldAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 7):

Your error is related to this : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html

Which is an attribute supposed to be in UnityEngine namespace (assembly UnityEngine.CoreModule) and exist in several versions of Unity (so it doesn't appear to be a problem due to an API change across versions).

Also, did you write it properly ? I notice "SerializedField" instead of "SerializeField" in your error message, which seems weird. You should have a second look on it.

Are you sure to have all runtimes installed for Unity, all required "using" and assembly references, and all tools (Visual Studio) up to date ?

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be [SerializeField], I had [Serialize**d**Field].

Sorry! Thanks for your reply AFract.